# wix Burn bootstrapper crash issue if cancel button is clicked

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, burn

I am trying to create a Wix burn bootstrapper that installs .Net framework 4 as prerequisite and then installs my msi. The bootstrapper exe is working fine but the only issue is that whenever I try to cancel the installation in midway the bootstrapper crashes. Please help me to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: WiX 3.6 is still in beta.  I suggest you email the wix-users list over at sourceforge and see if they can help.  They might ask you to file a bug report.

Comment: Have you tried this again now that the final version of WiX 4.6 has been released?

Answer (score 2):

This bug was fixed. Please upgrade to RTM version of WiX v3.6 or later.

Comment: Rob, the issue is still there in the latest stable release of WiX (v3.8), but has manifested itself slightly differently. After hitting Install, after UAC is up and you hit "Yes", you need to click on Cancel RIGHT-AWAY, lightning fast (during the Initializing phase). Once the "Are you sure you want to cancel dialog comes up", click on "No", then click Cancel again. This time, once you hit Cancel, it will freeze.

Comment: Some event viewer logs on this: `The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2884. The arguments are: FatalErrorForm, ,(NULL) (NULL) (NULL) (NULL) (NULL)`, and just **before** that, I get the same message except `The arguments are: SplashForm, ,(NULL) (NULL) (NULL) (NULL) (NULL)`

Comment: Also, erro code 2884 is `Failed to create a window for the dialog.` according to http://desktopengineer.com/msierrors

Comment: Sometimes, it will freeze on the second Cancel instantly, and sometimes you may first need to select Yes or No on the second Cancel for it to freeze, but provided you click the first Cancel during the Initializing phase, the second Cancel always leads to a freeze-up. :)

Comment: Now, that all being said, as part of my bundle I have an `MsiPackage` with `DisplayInternalUI="yes"` that it is trying to display at that point in time.